# Use of "sleek" as a noun

Tags: meaning, nouns

I encountered a polishing cloth that has a line which says

> (This cloth) generates **sleeks** and scratches on the glass surface.

What is the definition of *sleek* in this context? I looked up in a dictionary and all it says is *gloss, smooth surface*, but from the context it seems *sleek* is associated with *scratch*.

Comment: Although they’re clearly not appropriate to your context, *sleek* has several other obscure noun meanings: a measure of fruit or vegetables; a mud-bank; or an oily patch on water (parallel to *slick*).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

["Sleek"](http://www.unitedlens.com/page182.html) is a term used in polishing that means:

> Sleek - A polishing scratch having no visible conchoidal breaking of the edges.

[Another polishing site](http://www.atmsite.org/contrib/Poulson/faq/atmsect6.html) gives a better definition:

> A very fine scratch visible at only certain angles. Sleeks are found during polishing, usually being caused by impurities in the polishing compound or other contaminates. Sleeks also occur when the polishing compound dries out during a polishing session.

It is used specifically for polishing scratches.